# Including cURL in makefile

Tags: linux, curl, c, gnu-make

I'm using curl in my code and running through Makefile. but while running with "make" command its giving error like "curl/curl.h: No such file or directory". Here below is my makefile content.
`

```
CXX = /home/directory/Documents/xyz/l4t-gcc/bin/aarch64-buildroot-linux-gnu-cc
path = /home/directory/Documents/xyz/l4t-gcc/bin/
CFLAGS = -Wall
#INCLUDE = -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include -Iinclude
#LDFLAGS = -L/usr/local/lib -I/usr/lib
LDLIBS = -lcurl

SOURCES = src/sms_wrapper.c src/twilio.c
OUT = bin/sms_wrapper

all: build

build: $(SOURCES)
        $(CXX) -o $(OUT) $(CFLAGS) $(SOURCES) $(LDLIBS)

clean:
        rm -rf bin/sms_wrapper
`
```

I installed curl and added all things in Makefile which is needed for curl library. Does anyone have any suggestions or idea for resolving this thing !

Answer (score 0):

You need the "**-L**" option to specify where gcc will find the curl library specified in the "**-l**" option.

I dont' see that above in your script.

Maybe remove comment from your "**LDFLAGS**" definition and add the "**${LDFLAGS}**" on the line under your build target.

There is more detail on that requirement **[here](https://amir.rachum.com/shared-libraries/#rpath-and-runpath)**.